# Evaluate the Integral : $\int_{2}^{1}\frac{dt}{8-3t}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int^2_1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{8-3t}$$

> The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
> Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.
>
> 1. If $g(x) =\int^x_0 f(t)\ dt$, then $g'(x)=f(x)$
> 2. $\int^b_a\ f(x)\ dx=F(b)-F(a)$, where $F$ is any anti-derivative of $f$,  that is $F'=f$

Am I using the fundamental theorem of Calculus to solve this problem?

$$\frac{1}{8-6}-\frac{1}{8-3}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{5} = \frac{3}{10}$$

Am I right?

If not please show me the formula I should use and the steps.

Comment: You are stating that $$\int_{1}^{2}f(x)\,dx = f(2)-f(1).$$ Think about that.

Comment: Your statement is absolutely fine. However, I believe that you have understood it incorrectly. Try re-reading your statement more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're saying is $$\int_1^2 f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(2) - f(1).$$

Note that the theorem you stated in the question says $$\int_1^2 f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = F(2) - F(1)$$ where $F = \int f \, \mathrm{d}x \neq f$.

You'd need to evaluate the anti-derivative first to get $$\int^2_1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{8-3t}=-\frac13\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t-\frac83}=-\frac13 \left[\ln \left| t-\frac83\right| \right]_1^2=\ln\left(\frac52\right).$$

Where $$F = -\frac13 \ln |8-3t| + \mathrm{C}$$

If you differentiate $F$ to get $F'$, you'll see that it equals your function $f$, which fits in with the theorem you stated in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You may just write
$$
\int^2_1\frac{dt}{8-3t}=-\frac13\int_1^2\frac{1}{t-\frac83}dt=-\frac13 \left[\ln \left| t-\frac83\right| \right]_1^2=\frac13 \ln\left(\frac52\right).
$$

Comment: I don't see how the rule I wrote and your answer are related. Can you explain?

Comment: @Cetshwayo Yes. Here we have $\displaystyle F'(t):=-\frac13\left(\ln \left| t-\frac83\right| \right)'=\frac{1}{8-3t}=f(t)$. Thanks.